# devise doesn't send the correct reset password token on update

Tags: ruby-on-rails, devise, change-password

I'm using devise 3.5 with Rails 4.2.5, mongoid 5, and ruby 2.2.3 .

I've added the recovarable module , the email get sent successfully and on clicking the edit password link I get routed to http://localhost:3000/researchers/password/edit?reset_password_token=###

I went to mongo shell to verify that the reset token in the url is the correct one and it is.

Now when I put the new password and click "change" I get "invalid reset token", I can see clearly from webbrick console that devise sends find query to mongodb with the wrong reset password token and I don't know why.

I tried localizing :reset_password_sent_at and tried to require the reset_token on passwords edit page(that is Rails strong parameters) but nothing worked.

I've seen other questions on SO but most of them are using old version of Rails,devise or see messages other than mine, The devise wiki doesn't have a How-to for recoverable and all example apps don't have mailers.

All I have is confirmable,registrable,database_authenticatable besides recoverable on my model and all the controllers are copied from devise's one without change(except after_pathes and configure params).

So what to do ?

### Edit

this is my passwords controller:

```
  class Researchers::PasswordsController  < Devise::PasswordsController 
  before_action :permit_reset,only: [:edit]
  # GET /resource/password/new
  def new
    super
  end

  # POST /resource/password
  def create
    super
  end

  # GET /resource/password/edit?reset_password_token=abcdef
  def edit
    super
  end

  # PUT /resource/password
  def update
    super
  end

  protected
  def permit_reset
    params.require(:reset_password_token)
  end
  # def after_resetting_password_path_for(resource)
  #   super(resource)
  # end

  # The path used after sending reset password instructions
  # def after_sending_reset_password_instructions_path_for(resource_name)
  #   super(resource_name)
  # end
end
```

Comment: Could you put the code you are using in your Controller do to this?

Comment: @BrunoPaulino I have updated my question